# MySQL automate update of table data

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one temporary called Persons, the 2nd permanent called employee.

The temporary table is updated by someone every few hours and contains two fields, firstname and lastname.

The permanent table is called employee.  It is our permanent record of employees and includes all of their contact information, etc.  Importanly, it includes two fields firstname and lastname.

I have this query that shows me if a record in persons matches a record in employees.

SELECT T.FirstName, CASE WHEN P.FirstName IS NULL THEN 'DOES NOT EXIST' ELSE 'DOES EXIST' END
FROM employee T
   LEFT JOIN Persons P ON T.FirstName = P.FirstName AND T.LastName = P.LastName

I want something to run within MySQL, on a constant basis and do 2 things:

1. If a name matches in firstname and lastname in the Persons table and the employee table I want to receive an email that says "Duplicate employee found".  AND, I want it to add just those two fields to the employee table then remove the record from the Persons table.
2. If there is no match, I just want it to add those two fields to a new row in employee table and remove the row from Persons.

I know it sounds backwards but I have thought it through.  I can do a query, but I need MySQL to do this automatically on a periodic basis somehow.

Would love your help.

Comment: Can the FirstName in Employee be NULL? If not, you're going to be losing rows because you're joining on Employee.FirstName = Person.FirstName. This isn't an answer to your question, but I just wanted to point it out.

Comment: A second comment: if you have a match between the Employee and Persons table on FirstName and LastName, why do you want to add this to the Employee table? Isn't it already in the Employee table?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 5.1 introduced a feature called **Events**, which allows you to execute a block of procedure code on a schedule (like cron).

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/events.html